# Get specific cell from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, position, rank, index-error

I am programming a dynamic dataframe with players, values (=donated trees), rank and position as columns.
The players play a game and are able to self set the values. The higher the values, the higher the rank and position.
In the end of the game, I want to show them their position solely, something like your position is x out of total.

However, if I execute it in Python, I get an error message:

> "Index Error: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" in the line of end_Position

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, 'Donated Trees': trees})
df['Rank'] = df['Donated Trees'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['Position'] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int)
df.set_index('Rank', inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by="Donated Trees", ascending=False)
end_position = str(df.loc[df['Name'] == self.player.name, 'Position'].iloc[0])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: `from scipy.stats import rankdata
from itertools import count
import collections as ct
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

names = ['Tim', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Kyle']
values = [2, 4, 5, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names,'Values': values})
columns = ["Name", "Values"]
df['Rank'] = df['Values'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['Position'] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int)
df[df['Name'] == "Sam"]
print(" ".join(["Your current position is", str(df.loc[df['Name'] == "Sam", 'Position'].iloc[0]), "of", str(len(df))]))`

Comment: Oh dear that looks quite messy, I am sorry for that, quite new to stack overflow. I created an example with 4 players for you

Comment: Please include a sample of your DataFrame.

Comment: The sample is available under the following Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgLOe.png

Answer (score 0):

So, the error message you shared is the error message you will get when the `self.player.name` does not occur in the "Name" column.

However, I think you made a design error here. You set "Rank" as an index. Ideally you use the index as a unique field that allows fast retrieval of the rows of interest. As "Rank" is not unique and you also make not use of the fast retrieval function, I would not advise that. Instead you should make "Name" the index. You already use it twice for retrieval and it is most likely to be unique. (Best is to make sure somehow, but in your code you already assume "Name" is unique.) This way you have improved the efficiency of your code, the readability and you will get the more understandable `KeyError: "Bob"`, with "Bob" the key not in your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, 'Donated Trees': trees})
df['Rank'] = df['Donated Trees'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
df['Position'] = df['Rank'].rank(method='min').astype(int)
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by="Donated Trees", ascending=False)
print(" ".join(["Your current position is", str(df.loc["Sam", 'Position']), "of", str(len(df))]))
end_position = str(df.loc[self.player.name, 'Position'])
```